# Ubuntu with Unity DE keeps freezing

Tags: unity, 20.04

So, I decided to install Unity DE with my Ubuntu installation, but sometimes whenever I try to open an application through dock, search for something, really anything, it freezes for a few seconds. It got so bad that my computer randomly did a restart of Unity. This happens sometimes, sometimes not. This does not seem to happen when using Gnome. It also does not seem to happen if I don't change settings in Unity tweaks or Gnome tweaks.

What could be happening?

Edit: I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 with Unity DE

Comment: Oh, forgot to add that but tagged. It is 20.04

Comment: Unity was abandoned by Canonical/Ubuntu some time ago.  It's not really the most polished desktop.  Switching desktop environments on an installed system is prone to causing issues, and this is the reason that Ubuntu comes in so many official flavors.  Maybe these Unity configs are in conflict with whatever DE you originally installed.  One path around this is to install Ubuntu server (no DE) and then install the DE on top of that.